# Encode a string (characters and numbers) to a string with only character from a-z (BaseN)

Tags: java, encoding

does anybody know a function or library that converts Strings into character only (a-zA-Z) strings? Maybe there is a BaseN implementation that meets my requirements.

Maybe I didn't write it so cleary, so I am trying again. I need a way to encode e.g. JGHSDJ67-878DUSDd-3434 to a String like aaazzzttteeehhheeerrr (no numbers allowed here)
Second I need a way to decode "aaazzzttteeehhheeerrr" back to JGHSDJ67-878DUSDd-3434

Base32 looks fine but Base32 contains numeric values e.g.
"JGHSDJ67-878DUSDd-3434" would be "JJDUQU2EJI3DOLJYG44EIVKTIRSC2MZUGM2A====" Base32 encoded. As you can see there are still numeric values, cause they are define in BASE32. So what I am looking for is an encoding which is only based on characters a-z.

Comment: So remove non [a-zA-Z]? Or what happens to a `$` or `%` etc?

Comment: Seems like nobody answering and commenting in this thread gets what OP needs. OP asks for a way to ENCODE given normal text into a text made only of [a-zA-Z] characters. So, any digits and special characters must be represented somehow as [a-zA-Z] characters as well, in the resulting text. As we are talking about ENCODING this operation must be reversible, therefore solutions that involve simply removing characters out of [a-zA-Z] range are unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
    String hello = "Hello!! :)";
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(hello.getBytes());
    String base32 = bi.toString(32);
```

This transforms the byte codes of the string into a single binary number and then formats that number in base 32.

Comment: how about upper case.. 32 ? a-z is 26 * 2 + 10  ?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to remove all numeric and special characters?

try this: `String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\P{L}", "");`

Answer (score -2):

This might work

```
String newString = yourString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]","");
```

I've not tested it, but the idea is to use Java replaceAll function to replace anything that is not a character. I know you asked for a library but as you tagged it with Java I assume you could use some code?

EDIT: The above code will take your String and remove any characters that are NOT a-z or A-Z.

Comment: The OP's question was about a way of encoding full range of characters into [a-zA-Z] range not about deleting characters out of range, as the encoding operation must be reversible.